# Write a formula via Python starting on specific row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a code that would insert a formula starting at a specific rows but having no luck. Current code creates the formula for the whole column while I need it to start at row 5 and go until the end of the data set. Please let me know if you have a solution

```
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, keep_vba = True)
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Roster')
    for I, cell in enumerate(sheet['V'], 1):
        cell.value = '=Left($U{0},1)'.format(I)
    wb.save(file)
```

Comment: why don't you first select the dataframe you need? `df.iloc[5:,:]`

Comment: @RajithThennakoon sorry im still a newbie, where would I drop that in?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,
first load excel as dataframe and select only records you need

```
from  openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
book = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",sheet_name="Roster")
df = book.iloc[5:,:]
```

next convert dataframe to openpyxl object which you can do the rest of the work

```
sheet = dataframe_to_rows(df)
//do your operations
```